# How to use erf to calculate a probability in matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

Given a min and max value as well as the N number of items, I need to calculate the probability that the total sum of N items will be greater than or equal to an inputted value LM. The function handle:

```
function Pr = LoadPr(Wmin,Wmax,N,LM)
```

Another function:

```
function [muL, sigmaL, L ] = plane(Wmin,Wmax,N,M)
    [muW,sigmaW] = package(Wmin,Wmax);
    //  This calculates mu and sigma for a single item
    muL = muW*N;
    sigmaL = sigmaW*N^0.5;
    L = normrnd(muL,sigmaL,1,M);
end
```

This function calculates mu and sigma as well  as L is an 1 x M
array of randomly generated numbers that simulate M outcomes of randomly generated outcomes using sigmaL and muL given similar arguments as the previous function.

I also want to utilize the erf and/or erfc functions. 
An example:

```
Wmin = 2; Wmax = 10; N = 10000; LM = 60400;
Pr = LoadPr(Wmin,Wmax,N,LM )
Pr =
    0.0416
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the value of the N items normally distributed or uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 2):

The sum of N uniformly distributed values in a range `[min,max]` can be approximated as a normal distribution (for N>30) with a mean of `0.5*N*(min+max)` and a standard deviation of $sqrt(N*(max-min)/12)$.

Now the cumulative distribution of the Gaussian is given by

```
phi = 0.5*(1+erf((x-mu)/(sqrt(2)*sigma));
```

This means that the probability of the sum of 32 values between 0 and 6 will be distributed with

```
mean = 96
sigma = sqrt(32*6/12) = 4
```

And the probability that the sum is less than 88 would be given by

```
p = 0.5*(1+erf((88-96)/(sqrt(2)*4)) = 2.3%
```

Comment: "and a standard deviation of $sqrt(N*(max-min)/12)$." I'm a programmer new to this, and don't understand where that "12" constant is coming from. Is it specific to the OP's question, or is it somehow general to the problem of calculating the probability of results relative to PRNG 0-1 generated numbers?

Comment: @Venryx the standard deviation of a uniform distribution follows the expression I gave quite generally (in the limit of a very large number of samples it becomes exact). You could convince yourself by taking the standard deviation of 1000 numbers 0.001 ... 1.000 or 1 ... 1000 for example.

Comment: Okay; I just don't understand on an intuitive level where the 12 came from. Whenever I first see an equation for something and I notice a seemingly arbitrary constant like 12, 34, and 59, I'm immediately interested in understanding where it came from. Like, why is that constant exactly 12, rather than 15, 18, or 21? (if this involves too complicated of an explanation, feel free to ignore -- it's just a curiosity for me)

Comment: Oh, I seem to have stumbled upon an explanation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728059/prove-variance-in-uniform-distribution-continuous

Comment: I’m glad you found your answer